# рассылка сообщений всем кто находится на сервере

Tags: python, discord.py

хочу добавить для своего бота рассылку сообщений всем участникам сервера в лс

как это сделать?

Вот код

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message):
for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
await client.send(member, message)

Comment: Покажите свой код, как вы питаетесь это сделать.

Comment: @client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        await client.send(member, message)

Comment: пожалуйста, внесите информацию непосредственно в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]